# In iPad Air(iOS7.1.2) My tableviews cell appears in single line, one above another

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

This works fine in all other devices with same OS Version.

When I use following methods in code this happens

```
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return  CELL_HEIGHT;
}

-(float)tableView:(UITableView*) tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CELL_HEIGHT;
}
```

In my Application I have to return different cell height and header height depending on the section and other results.

I have checked by setting size in xib and code as same. Also checked by setting the sizes in  xib to zero and returning correct height from code.

Comment: Does it happens on iPhone 5s? Try to change (float) to (CGFloat).

Comment: send me the how you are caliculating cell height dynamically

Comment: @trick you are right it worked when changed to CGFloat

Comment: Good for you. I should better leave as an answer. =)

Comment: @trick: sorry:) I removed my answer its yours